# python, sqlalchemy check for None with == raises argument error

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a query which tries to get list of users for a particular set of events which joins with the user table to check if the user is not marked for a particular flag "dnd" (flag column could have a null value too). The query goes something like this:

```
query = session.query(Event.uid).filter(Event.event.in_(event_list)).\
        join(User, and_((User.id == Event.uid), \
        or_(User.flag == None, User.flag != "dnd")))
```

It raises an Argument error exception

```
ArgumentError("Only '=', '!=', 'is_()', 'isnot()' operators can
be used with None/True/False",)
```

I've tried other possibilities/suggestions (listed below) but still get the same error:

1. using # noqa
2. checking "User.Flag is None"
3. checking "User.Flag.is_(None)"

In other places, when I'm checking only with the User table without a join, it seems to work. For eg:

```
User.query.filter(User.flag == None, User.flag != "dnd").all()
```

works.

DB being used is postgresql.

How do I check for NULL value within this join?

Comment: Try moving the query parts about the flag into a filter call rather than including them into the join.

Comment: No luck, same error.

Comment: Please include your model definitions, and the full traceback.